# Python Autobahn Websocket Server Receving One connection at a time

Tags: websocket, autobahn

Python Asyncio or Twisted used by Autobahn are supposed to Handle concurrent connection at the same time.
I followed a good tutorial on autobahn read-the-doc, it all worked well, yet the server is receiving only one connection and process it's request and then after that accept a second one.

How can I ensure that the server receives multiple connection cocurrently without holding other connecting peer?

I have searched across the web the whole day but no success
here is my code(I have cut out a lot of code while debugging)

```py
from autobahn.asyncio.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol
from autobahn.asyncio.websocket import WebSocketServerFactory

class NMmapperServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):
    cmd = NMmapperWSCommandParser() # I have cut out this due to debugging

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        """
        @payload the message
        @isBinary whether it's a binary message
        """
        try:
            offload_payload = json.loads(payload.decode("utf-8"))
            await asyncio.gather(cmd.processWSCommands(offload_payload, self))
        except Exception as e:
            raise

    def onConnect(self, request):
        """
        When we've got a peer connect to our server
        """
        try:
            #print(self)
            print(request.peer, "Has connected")
        except Exception as e:
            raise

    def onOpen(self):
        """
        We have a fully connection
        """
        try:
            # Some database action can be made from here
            print("Connection now opened")
        except Exception as e:
            raise

    def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
        """
        @ the client is closing his or her
        connection
        """
        try:
            print("wasClean ", wasClean)
            print("code ", code)
            print("reason ", reason)
        except Exception as e:
            raise

    # Setters
    def setCsrftoken(self, cookie_string):
        """
        @ parse an set
        """
        self.csrftoken = self.parse_csrftoken(cookie_string)

    # Setters
    def setSession(self, cookie_string):
        """
        @ parse an set
        """
        self.session = self.parse_session(cookie_string)


if __name__=="__main__":
    if(IN_PRODUCTION):
        print("RUNNING ")
        factory = NMmapperWSServerFactory(PRODUCTION_HOST, PRODUCTION_PORT)
        factory.run_loop()
    else:
        print("Running on dev")
        factory = WebSocketServerFactory()
        factory.protocol = NMmapperServerProtocol
        
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        coro = loop.create_server(factory, '0.0.0.0', 9000)
        server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
        
        try:
            loop.run_forever()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
        finally:
            server.close()
            loop.close()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working as expected. Being an asyncio library
i had to prefix async on each method that performs long running task

The Problem was with the onMessage, I had to process the messages in parallel
not to block the other clients wanting to process there messages also.
so to do that i had to

```
offload_payload = json.loads(payload.decode("utf-8"))
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

# Offload command processing
loop.create_task(self.processWSCommands(offload_payload, self))
```

This way every message is processed in parallel
Even in such an instance ensure that the method or function processing the message don't block.

```
from autobahn.asyncio.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol
from autobahn.asyncio.websocket import WebSocketServerFactory

class NMmapperServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):
    cmd = NMmapperWSCommandParser() # I have cut out this due to debugging

    async def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        """
        @payload the message
        @isBinary whether it's a binary message
        """
        try:
            offload_payload = json.loads(payload.decode("utf-8"))
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            #loop.create_task(runner(10, self.peer))
            #asyncio.gather(runner(20, self.peer))

            # Offload command processing
            loop.create_task(self.processWSCommands(offload_payload, self))
        except Exception as e:
            raise

    def onConnect(self, request):
        """
        When we've got a peer connect to our server
        """
        try:
            #print(self)
            print(request.peer, "Has connected")
        except Exception as e:
            raise

    def onOpen(self):
        """
        We have a fully connection
        """
        try:
            # Some database action can be made from here
            print("Connection now opened")
        except Exception as e:
            raise

    def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
        """
        @ the client is closing his or her
        connection
        """
        try:
            print("wasClean ", wasClean)
            print("code ", code)
            print("reason ", reason)
        except Exception as e:
            raise

    # Setters
    def setCsrftoken(self, cookie_string):
        """
        @ parse an set
        """
        self.csrftoken = self.parse_csrftoken(cookie_string)

    # Setters
    def setSession(self, cookie_string):
        """
        @ parse an set
        """
        self.session = self.parse_session(cookie_string)


if __name__=="__main__":
    if(IN_PRODUCTION):
        print("RUNNING ")
        factory = NMmapperWSServerFactory(PRODUCTION_HOST, PRODUCTION_PORT)
        factory.run_loop()
    else:
        print("Running on dev")
        factory = WebSocketServerFactory()
        factory.protocol = NMmapperServerProtocol

        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        coro = loop.create_server(factory, '0.0.0.0', 9000)
        server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

        try:
            loop.run_forever()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
        finally:
            server.close()
            loop.close()
```